# Java - Working with multiple Boolean attributes as flags

Tags: java, boolean, flags

What is a more efficient and maintainable (ie, better) way for my "MyObject" object class to have many 'flags' (25 currently)?

My program is conceptually geared around mathematical Set theory. So, the user will query a number of sets to return which MyObjects are members of those sets, mainly using the Intersection of Sets

This is the essence of where I'm struggling:

Each MyObject will have 25 'flags'. These flags determine whether a MyObject is able to be put in one of the previously mentioned sets.

My question is, how can I program these flags?

I have gravitated toward Booleans. This means that any query or adding of MyObject to a set, can be dependant on whether the flag is On or Off, 1 or 0, True of False.

For example, I want to assign five MyObjects to a set called North. As each MyObject is assigned to the set, a check would be performed to look for the flag. If the flag is negative/off/false, the object will NOT be assigned, and an error message returned.

So far, I have used Booleans. Lets say for example, in the constructor:

```
{

String "Attribute1"
String "Attribute2"
String "Attribute3"

Boolean flag1 = false
Boolean flag2 = false
Boolean flag3 = false
Boolean flag4 = false

}
```

Later, one of my methods allows users to 'add' or flip a flag to reflect a MyObject gaining that flag attribute. For example:

```
public void flipFlag(true){
    this.flag == true;
}
```

So far so good.

This allows me to do what I want: add MyObjects to numerous sets if they have the right flag.
But the problem comes when I think about other operations on these flags. There will be 25 of them, so I want to be able to Iterate over these booleans when necessary. I want to try to limit the number of times this 'list' of flags is replicated so that, in future, when I add, remove or change these flags, there is one or two places to edit, not dozens (I currently need a separate method to flip each boolean because I can only parse true, false or null as a method argument).

I also need to be able to iterate over the flags to return the set of True flags, the set of False flags or both.

I thought I might have a HashMap of Booleans, but this has proven difficult

In my head, I want the hash map to be:

```
Key : Value
flag1 : true
flag2 : false
flag3 : false
```

But that's not how it works it seems.
Any help or pointers are appreciated. I have looked over many similar questions on Stack but they are not quite providing the answers I need.

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: How do you decide the total number of flags (build vs runtime)? How does the check happen? Does the caller know all the flags in the object?

Comment: Total number of flags should not change outside of software updates (in fact, extremely rarely so), so, at build time. The checks will happen frequently, as the user will assign MyObjects regularly to different Sets, and they will know all the flags, they'll eventually be easily accessible in the GUI.

Comment: If it is build time, how about a `HashMap<Feature,Boolean>` where `Feature` is an enum? That could bring in a little more "strict"ness

Comment: I'm going to look into enums as this has been suggested to me also. I think @tim-moore 's answer will do everything I need, but I'm still going to look into a solution involving enum too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java contains a standard class called [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) for this purpose. It is a compact representation of a sequence of boolean values, accessed by an `int` index. The usual way to use it is to define constants or `enum` values for the indexes in the parent class. For example:

```
public static final int FLAG1 = 0;
public static final int FLAG2 = 1;
// ... and so on

private BitSet flags = new BitSet(25); // or however many flags you need
```

You can then access individual flags with:

```
flags.get(FLAG1);
```

set them with:

```
flags.set(FLAG1, true);
```

or flip them (i.e., reverse the value) with:

```
flags.flip(FLAG1);
```

There are many other operations available. Check the API documentation for details.

Comment: This is perfect, it allows me to do what I need to accomplish with a lot of flexibility, thank you! I'm just experimenting with it now. Trying to see if I should have separate BitSets for each flag or whether I can use a sets of them. Thanks again!

Comment: You would put all of your flags into one BitSet. Glad this helps!